# C sockets: why is my server adding extra strings when i give input to my client?

Tags: c, sockets, client-server

Ive been trying to create a client-socket server that accepts input from the keyboard and translate strings that you type into requests to the server.
This is my server code:

```
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <netinet/in.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#include<arpa/inet.h>
int main(int argv, char *afgv[]){ 
int socket_desc, c,read_size;
long unsigned int client_socket ;
struct sockaddr_in server, client;
//char client_message[1000];
// get a socket
socket_desc = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM,0); 
if (socket_desc==-1){ 
 printf("Could not create socket.");
}
puts("Socket created");
//fill the fields 
server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
server.sin_family =AF_INET; 
server.sin_port = htons( 8888 ); 
//bind the socket to the port
if(bind(socket_desc,(struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server))<0){ 
perror("bind faild. error");
return 1;
}
//start listening for incoming connections
puts("bind done");
listen(socket_desc,3);
puts("waiting for incoming connections...");
c = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
client_socket= accept(socket_desc,(struct sockaddr *)&client, (socklen_t*)&c);
if (client_socket == -1) {
      perror("accept falid");
      return 1;
    }
puts("Connection accepted");
//while(read_size=recv(client_socket, client_message, 2000,0)>0) { 
while(1){
char client_message[1000];
recv(client_socket, client_message, 2000,0);
puts(client_message);
write(client_socket,client_message, strlen(client_message));  
}
 
if(read_size==0){ 
  puts("client disconnected");
  fflush(stdout);
}
else if(read_size==-1){
 perror("recv failed");
}
 
return 0;
}
```

My client code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>  
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sock;
    struct sockaddr_in server;
    //char message[1000], server_reply[2000];
    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sock == -1) 
        printf("ERROR opening socket"); 
    puts("Socket created");
    server.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1");   
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons(8888);
    if (connect(sock,(struct sockaddr *)&server,sizeof(server)) < 0){ 
        printf("ERROR connecting");
return 1;
}
    puts("Connected");
while(1){
    char message[1000], server_reply[2000];
    printf("Please enter the message: ");
    scanf("%s",message);
    puts(message);
    if (send(sock,message,strlen(message),0)< 0){ 
         printf("ERROR writing to socket");
return 1;
}
     
   if (recv(sock,server_reply,2000,0)<0){
puts("recv failed");
break;
}
puts("server reply");
puts(server_reply);
}
close(sock);
    return 0;
}
```

My problem right now is that whenever I use the client server to try and send something my messsage always comes back with some extra characters at the end

Comment: Please show how you are determining that the server is "adding extra string". The server is not sending the NUL character. But since you have not shown the client code we can't see whether it is handling that correctly - my crystal ball says that your client code is trying to print a non-NUL terminated character sequence.

Comment: ⟼Remember, it's always important, *especially* when learning and asking questions on Stack Overflow, to keep your code as organized as possible. [Consistent indentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) helps communicate structure and, importantly, intent, which helps us navigate quickly to the root of the problem without spending a lot of time trying to decode what's going on.

Comment: "Extra characters" sounds a lot like "I accidentally specified the wrong length when writing a buffer out". It looks like you used to check the result from `recv` but then were like "Nah, that's not important". Guess what? **It is**.

Comment: Consider using `getaddrinfo` to setup the socket parameters. The method you are using is outdated as it supports only IPv4.

Answer (score 1):

The code is outputting a non-terminated string.  This is the "extra characters".

Consider the code:

```
while(1) 
{
    char client_message[1000];
    recv(client_socket, client_message, 2000,0);
    puts(client_message);
    write(client_socket,client_message, strlen(client_message));  
}
```

This is reading all content sent, but probably the transmit was to the `strlen()` of the message, and so the terminating NUL byte `\0` is not part of the data.  So the `puts()` simply keeps writing out characters to the console.  Under the wrong conditions it will crash, but luckily it happened to find a stray `0` randomly left inside `client_message`, and stopped there.

There's a few ways around this.

I think the best method is to check the amount of data received - the return result from `recv()`, and then terminate the buffer at that point.

```
while(1) 
{
    char client_message[1000];
    ssize_t bytes_rxd = recv(client_socket, client_message, sizeof( client_message ), 0);

    if ( bytes_rxd == 0 )
    {
        printf( "Socket closed by client\n" );
        break;
    }
    else if ( bytes_rxd < 0 )
    {
        printf( "Error on socket\n" );
        break;
    }
    else if ( bytes_rxd >= sizeof( bytes_rxd ) )
    {
        // input buffer is completely full, discard the last character to terminate
        printf( "Message Truncated\n" );
        client_message[ sizeof( client_message ) - 1 ] = '\0';
    }
    else
    {
        // partially full buffer, terminate after the message
        client_message[ bytes_rxd ] = '\0';
    }

    puts( client_message );

    write(client_socket,client_message, strlen(client_message));  
}

close( client_socket );  // connection is over.
```

Obviously I also added buffer size range-checking too.  This is important for software quality and security.  The code was willing to accept 2000 characters, but only had space for 1000.

Comment: The server doesnt add extra characters anymore when its displayed on the server page but when i try to get a reply using my client code the extra characters show again.

Comment: @Jake - You're still sending a `strlen()` worth of bytes from the server right?  So it's likely the same issue, except on the client side.  Ensure the client uses the result from `recv()`, and/or terminate the string.